# Aggregate Count rows that have the same values in two columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am pretty new to SQL and am struggling with a slightly more advanced query. I have query which returns a sorted table like so:

## Updated Query:

I mistakenly posted the wrong query. Here is the correct, similar query.

```
SELECT distinct T.AidId  ,A.FirstName  ,A.LastName  ,T.EventName,  
FROM AidsDB.dbo.AidsInfo A  
JOIN AidsDB.dbo.TextsInfo T 
ON A.AidId = T.AidId
```

What I need to do is find how many rows within the table have matching values of `AideId` and `EventName` and return the number in a new column to be shown to users. The query result is being bound to a `WebDataGrid` and I will eventually be dealing with large amounts of data.

Among others, I have found the following sources helpful, but cant seem to get it to work. This question addresses counting rows in a separate query: [Count Rows with same values in two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597055/how-to-count-rows-that-have-the-same-values-in-two-columns-sql)

```
SELECT  A,
        B,
        COUNT(*)
FROM the-table
GROUP BY A,B
```

The following shows how to add a column: [Add Column in SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882951/add-column-to-sql-query-results)

```
SELECT 'Site1' AS SiteName,
        t1.column1, 
        t1.column2
FROM the-table
```

Is there any way to combine these to to return a single table with data I want? Something like this maybe:

```
SELECT (Count(*) Where EventName = EventName and AidId AidId) as Responses,
        [TextTime], 
        [TextSender], 
        [TextContents], 
        [AidID], 
        [EventName] 
FROM [TextsInfo] ORDER BY [TextTime] DESC
```

Does this make any sense at all?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

## Update #1:

My data looks something like this:

#### Mesages Table:

```
AidID   TextContents    TextSender  TextTime                        EventName   
12345   Msg1             company1   2016-05-04 15:37:40.1522000     event1
12345   Reply to Msg1    John Doe   2016-05-04 15:38:29.0000000     event1
98765   Msg1             company1   2016-05-04 16:37:04.8458000     event1
```

#### Employee Info Table:

```
AidID   FirstName       LastName
12345   John            Doe
98765   Mike            Smith
```

#### Response Im looking for:

```
AidID   FirstName       LastName    EventName   Count
98765   Mike Smith      Smith       event1      1
12345   John            Doe         event1      2
```

The count column would be added based on how many messages for a specific Event each emloyee has. If they have more than one, it means they have responded. Otherwise they have not.

## Update #2

For anyone interested, this is my working query based on @M02's answer:

```
select distinct T.AidId  ,A.FirstName  ,A.LastName  ,T.EventName,
count(T.EventName + T.AidID) over(partition by T.EventName, T.AidID) cnt
from AidsDB.dbo.AidsInfo A  join  AidsDB.dbo.TextsInfo T on A.AidId = T.AidId
```

Comment: Please, add samples of data you have and what output you want.

Comment: Your final query does make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join the results from the group by query and get the results like this:

```
SELECT t.A,t.B,C,D,E,F,t1.cnt FROM the_table t
JOIN (SELECT A,B,COUNT(*) cnt FROM the_table GROUP BY A,B) t1
ON t.A = t1.A
AND t.B = t1.B
```

Here is another way to do it with an aggregate function:

```
SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F, 
  count(a + b) over(partition by a,b) cnt
FROM the_table t
```

You can see a demo of both of these methods here:
http://rextester.com/KVDY97918

Comment: Thanks!! This worked perfectly. I am using method two currently. My query has a join method(see updated post), is there a performance difference between using a nested query and an aggregate method in my case? Thanks.